# Bugs in loose leaf tea

Tags: tea

I had my first loose leaf tea today. Black tea, with pieces of dried fruit in it. As I was throwing the used leaves away, I noticed what seemed to be a dead worm. Is this at all common and safe, or should I get rid of the tea?

Comment: Can you post a picture of this "dead worm"? Perhaps someone here can identify what it is and if it's dangerous to the rest of the tea.

Comment: @Johanna I've already gotten rid of it, unfortunately. It was a tiny, black worm. I then checked the rest of the tea and didn't find any other bugs. It is hand-harvested, so I can see how the worm ended up in the packaging. Do you happen to know if it is common though?

Comment: The vast majority of all tea is harvested by hand, and hand harvesting would if anything make it less likely that there would be worms picked along with the leaves. I drink quite a bit of loose leaf tea and have never found a worm or any sort of bug in it. This question refers to general non-tea things in tea and may answer your question: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/90933/is-it-normal-to-find-something-in-tea?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears from another post that is indeed unusual to find foreign matter in loose leaf tea.  [Is it normal to find something in tea?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/90933/is-it-normal-to-find-something-in-tea)

That said, bugs in food are a fact of life.  Every food inspection agency has rules for how many bugs are allowed in different commodities. As a former grain inspector, I followed specific guidelines for how many bugs were allowed per lot. It isn't zero.

I wouldn't consider the tea unsafe because of the worm unless you found live worms or many worms.

Tea isn't listed, but you might find the USFDA list below informative.  It shows what rises to a level of concern for a number of foods.

https://www.fda.gov/food/ingredients-additives-gras-packaging-guidance-documents-regulatory-information/food-defect-levels-handbook#commodities